# What is wrong with this alter table query?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to add a column into mysql table using this query but mysql is complaining about syntax. I have seen number of sources but I am unable to see whats wrong here.

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE dog add date TIMESTAMP(14);
```

**error:**

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(14)'
 at line 1
```

table name 'dog', column name 'date'

Comment: Didn't think timestamp required the precision..   Alter table dog add column 'date' timestamp;

Comment: Yah sure youbetcha; everyone else had it, I just cleaned it up a bit :D

Comment: be sure to accept either interroban or carlo's answers; I believe they both have the correct updates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

DATE is a special word in MySQL, so you'll need to put backticks around it:

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE dog add `date` TIMESTAMP;
```

Comment: mysql> ALTER TABLE dog add `date` TIMESTAMP(14);
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(14)'
 at line 1

Comment: Yeah, remove the (14). I'm used to seeing it on INTs and didn't blink at you trying to put it on a TIMESTAMP. Answer updated.

Comment: Here's the list of all reserved words, which you need to backtick if your tables are called that: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/reserved-words/ and for MySQL: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html for Postgres: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html

Answer (score 1):

quote ALTER TABLE dog add `date` TIMESTAMP(14);  date is reserved word use alt + 96

that is the correct

```
 ALTER TABLE dog ADD `date` TIMESTAMP;
```

thats work checked

Answer (score 0):

date is a keyword in mysql, I'll suggest you use something else